# Enums with description and values as Integers

Tags: c#, enums, data-annotations

I am creating a dropdown and I need to define an enum with inegerlike this

```
Public enum Example
{
  [Description("Any")]
  0,
  [Description("1")]
  1,
  [Description("2")]
  2
}
```

I want to display integers and values also as integers.

It gives syntax or compilation errors. Please help

Comment: An enum field must be an identifier.  A number is not an identifier.

Comment: If it walks like a class, talks like a class, it probably should be a class.  Why do people keep trying to make enums do something they aren't meant for?  When you find you need more than just a value, create a class and then have `static readonly` instances.

Answer (score 2):

```
public enum Example
{
  [Description("Any")]
  Any = 0,
  [Description("1")]
  One = 1,
  [Description("2")]
  Two = 2
}
```

Comment: Enum.GetValues(typeof(Example) will give me Any, One, Two but I need 0,1, 2.

Comment: The values for my select dropdown should be 0,1,2 while displaying text as Any, 1, 2

Comment: you can cast the enum to int to get 0, 1, 2.